# InputMismatchException on a string to string

Tags: java

I am getting the `InputMismatchException` in a place where I don't think I should be getting it. I am asking the user to enter `cm` or `kg`, depending on which one they want to convert to. I use `sc.next` to get their input, but it is throwing the exception even though it is a string.

I have tried messing with different `sc.""` to see if I was using the wrong one. I also tried changing the String `userChoice = ""` to `cm` just to see what would happen (huge mess with lots of errors).

```
        String userChoice = " ";
        String userCont = "yes";

    System.out.println("\t\t\tWelcome to the Standard to Metric Converter.\n");

    while (userCont.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
    System.out.println("Type \"kg\" to convert to kilograms.");
    System.out.println("Type \"cm\" to convert to centimeters.");
    sc.next(userChoice);

    if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("cm")){
        System.out.println("You have chosen to convert feet and inches to "
                + "centimeters.");
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of feet: \n");
            sc.nextInt(conv.feet);
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of inches: \n");
            sc.nextInt(conv.inch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you're not actually assigning a new value to `userChoice` (which I suppose you try to do). You use `userChoice` as a pattern to look up for a new value, which is, by your example, is empty.

It should be:

```
userChoice = sc.next();
```

The same applies to the rest of the code.

Comment: I appreciate your help!  That works and makes sense why when I changed the things around I was still getting errors even after this InputMismatchException.